# Package import from script raises “AttributeError: module has no attribute”

Tags: python, camera

My goal is to acquire image from an Allied Vision camera thanks to Python (Anaconda 3.7). For that I tried to use the "Pymba" package but I get the error :  “AttributeError: module has no attribute”.
I looked in the previous posts but I didn't find any working solution. I put below some of my tests.
Here is my code :

```
import pymba

with pymba.Vimba() as vimba:

    print (vimba.getVersion())
    system = vimba.getSystem()
```

The precise error :

```
File "<ipython-input-2-ff80570a1f3d>", line 3, in <module>
print (vimba.getVersion())

AttributeError: 'Vimba' object has no attribute 'getVersion'
```

And here are some informations that could be usefull about my research to solve this problem:

I checked if the package was correctly installed.

```
from pymba import Vimba, PYMBA_VERSION

print(PYMBA_VERSION)
print(Vimba.version())
0.3.2
1.7.0
```

Despite the fact that I don't have any other file named "Pymba", I checked what file was imported:

```
print(pymba.__file__)
C:\Users\agricultu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymba\__init__.py
```

I don't have either a previous file named "getVersion" and I get the same error for every other function of the package anyway.

I'm running out of ideas and I hope one of you will be able to help me.

Comment: How did you get the idea that `pymba.Vimba` has a method `getVersion` (or `getSystem` for that matter)? You have used the correct method during your tests (`print(Vimba.version())`). With that instance `vimba` of `Vimba` in your code, you should use [`vimba.version()`](https://github.com/morefigs/pymba/blob/master/pymba/vimba.py#L17) and [`vimba.system()`](https://github.com/morefigs/pymba/blob/master/pymba/vimba.py#L71)

Comment: I got the idea from other codes like this one (http://anki.xyz/installing-pymba-on-windows/) or this one (https://gist.github.com/npyoung/1c160c9eee91fd44c587). The last one was edited Feb 27, 2019 so I assume that the code was up to date.

Comment: Fair enough :). However, the methods `getVersion` and `getSystem` have been replaced by properties in [this commit](https://github.com/morefigs/pymba/commit/530d7b1ef415e8be19f03852f204851271edeb87#diff-68732a283410112d845e8745c097ff89) on January 22nd. `version` has been turned into a static method on January 30th and `system` became an instance method on January 27th. I assume these changes have been in the PyPI package since pymba 0.3.